# Is it bad to call Destroy and New Context repeatedly?

Tags: java, spring

Let's say I have my **main class** like this:

```
public class TestTasker
{
    private static GenericXmlApplicationContext context; // to be accessed by static main

    public void runTask()
    {
        System.out.println("Current time is: " + new Date());

        context.destroy();
        initContext();

        // if I do this instead..
        // context.refresh();
        // I'd get an exception:
        // SEVERE: Invocation of method 'runTask' on target class [class spring.task.test.TestTasker] failed
        // java.lang.IllegalStateException: GenericApplicationContext does not support multiple refresh attempts: just call 'refresh' once

        // EDIT2: by using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext instead of generic context,
        // I can call context.refresh() with no error.
    }

    private static initContext()
    {
        context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("AppContext.xml");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        initContext();
    }
}
```

and **AppContext.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Task Scheduler -->
    <task:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="testTasker" class="spring.task.test.TestTasker" />
    <util:properties id="applicationProps" location="application.properties" />
    <context:property-placeholder
        properties-ref="applicationProps" />
    <task:scheduled-tasks>
        <task:scheduled ref="testTasker" method="runTask"
            cron="#{applicationProps['cron.expression']}" />
    </task:scheduled-tasks>

</beans>
```

and **application.properties**:

```
cron.expression=*/5 * * * * ?
```

Will, there be any negative consequences, such as memory leak, if I do that (calling destroy and new context repeatedly)?

Is there any better solution? I just need Spring to *refresh* AppContext automatically/periodically..

**EDIT**: edited the code in main class. calling `context.refresh()` would give this exception,

`SEVERE: Invocation of method 'runTask' on target class [class spring.task.test.TestTasker] failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GenericApplicationContext does not support multiple refresh attempts: just call 'refresh' once`

**EDIT2**: by using `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` instead of generic context I can call context.refresh() with no error though.

Comment: Why don't you just call refresh() then on the context, if you want to do that?

Comment: i don't think that this may lead to memory leak or anything bad, but it's very uncommon to do it. Usually you create one application context for the whole application. Maybe if you share the use case, we can find a better solution.

Comment: @dunni I can't call context.refresh() because it gives an exception:
SEVERE: Invocation of method 'runTask' on target class [class spring.task.test.TestTasker] failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GenericApplicationContext does not support multiple refresh attempts: just call 'refresh' once

Comment: @Evgeni this is just a proof of concept. I just want to dynamically update `application.properties` at runtime and the task schedule automatically updated, but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem with GenericXmlApplicationContext.refresh() is, it did not support multiple refresh . can you please share your updated code.it looks like it was called more than once after initialization.

here is what spring docs reads

In contrast to other ApplicationContext implementations that create a new internal BeanFactory instance for each refresh, the internal BeanFactory of this context is available right from the start, to be able to register bean definitions on it. AbstractApplicationContext.refresh() may only be called once.

For the typical case of XML bean definitions, simply use ClassPathXmlApplicationContext or FileSystemXmlApplicationContext, which are easier to set up - but less flexible, since you can just use standard resource locations for XML bean definitions, rather than mixing arbitrary bean definition formats. The equivalent in a web environment is XmlWebApplicationContext.

For custom application context implementations that are supposed to read special bean definition formats in a refreshable manner, consider deriving from the AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext base class.

Comment: Hi, what I mean by calling `main` is really just to call `context = new context`
But I was to lazy to even copy paste :p I'll fix the code, so there will be no more confusion.
Also, I use `static` cause `static main` can only access static variables..

Comment: The question is about is it a good idea to destroy and create context. It's not about the usage of main and static fields. Please reconsider editing your answer. *The code written here* may not be the actual code so, that can be ignored.

Comment: @Bhupi Thanks for the hint, by using `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` instead of generic context I can call `context.refresh()` with no error. Thanks again. And to answer you about the code, the codes above is really the whole project. I created a small project just to test Spring Task Scheduler. I just started to learn Spring few days ago :p

Answer (score 1):

You can use context.refresh();

it should destroy already created singletons if it fails, to avoid dangling resources. In other words, after invocation of that method, either all or no singletons at all should be instantiated.

Comment: Hi, if I call context.refresh() I get an exception:

`SEVERE: Invocation of method 'runTask' on target class [class pring.task.test.TestTasker] failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GenericApplicationContext does not support multiple refresh attempts: just call 'refresh' once`